# MySQL: getting a row count based on a correlated subquery of a subquery

Tags: mysql, count, correlated-subquery

I apologize if this has been answered else where, I've been pulling my hair out searching but haven't found anything yet.

I have the following tables:

```
    Table: STATES
+------------+---------+
| name       | stateID |
+------------+---------+
| Florida    |  FL     |
| California |  CA     |
| New Jersey |  NJ     |
+------------+---------+

Table: AREAS
+-------+---------+-------+
| name  | stateID | locID |
+-------+---------+-------+
| Area1 | FL      | 1     |
| Area2 | FL      | 1     |
| Area3 | FL      | 2     |
| Area4 | NJ      | 3     |
| Area5 | NJ      | 3     |
| Area6 | NJ      | 4     |
| Area7 | CA      | 5     |
| Area8 | CA      | 6     |
| Area9 | CA      | 7     |
+-------+---------+-------+

Table: LOCATIONS
+----------+-------+
| name     | locID |
+----------+-------+
| Orlando  | 1     |
| Brevard  | 2     |
| North NJ | 3     |
| South NJ | 4     |
| B Hills  | 5     |
| East LA  | 6     |
| SanFran  | 7     |
+----------+-------+
```

The result I'm trying to get is:

```
| STATES.name | LOCATIONS.name | COUNT(locations in state) | AREAS.name
```

I'm able to get everything but the count easily enough, but I just can't get how many locations are in each state. It seems like this should be a simple thing, am I just missing something?

Here's the query I've been working with:

```
SELECT 
    STATES.name AS state
    ,LOCATIONS.name AS location
    ,AREAS.name AS area
    ,(SELECT
        COUNT(*) 
     FROM 
        (SELECT
            areaID
        FROM
            AREAS
        WHERE 
            AREAS.stateID = STATES.stateID 
         GROUP BY 
            AREAS.locID
        ) AS area_count

    ) AS row_count
FROM
    STATES
    LEFT JOIN AREAS ON STATES.stateID = AREAS.stateID
    LEFT JOIN LOCATIONS ON AREAS.locID = LOCATIONS.locID;
```

Of course this fails due to there not being any STATES.stateID in subquery 1 for subquery 2 to reference. I've tried passing the stateID along by `JOIN`ing the table in subquery 1, as well as `JOIN`ing it in subquery 2 instead of trying to reference it in the `WHERE` statement. This also fails given that the whole of subquery 2 is part of the `WHERE` statement for subquery 1...

I've also tried isolating the queries to pull just `AREAS.stateID` and `COUNT(locations in state)` but to no avail, I keep getting the number of areas in the state, not the number of locations:

```
select AREAS.stateID
, COUNT(AREAS.locID)
FROM AREAS group by AREAS.stateID
```

Tossing a `DISTINCT` into the `COUNT()` gets me closer but some of the values are still off, not sure where it's getting the numbers from as they don't match the number of locations for all cases, but most of them...

Comment: Every location belongs to one and only one state, right? Then, why the `Locations` table doesn't have a `stateID` (as a foreign key)?

Comment: Can you show example output using data from your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

- every State has many Locations
  (1-to-many relationship)

and

- every Location has many Areas
  (1-to-many relationship)

So, there should be a `stateID` in table `Location` , as a foreign key to table `State`.

And there should be no need for a `stateID` in table `Area`

Then, you could have:

```
SELECT
    s.name         AS stateName
  , l.name         AS locationName
  , locgrp.locCnt  AS locationsInState           
  , a.name         AS areaName
FROM STATES s
  JOIN LOCATIONS l
    ON s.stateID = l.stateID
  JOIN AREAS a
    ON a.locationID = l.locationID
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT stateID
           , COUNT(*) AS locCnt
      FROM LOCATIONS 
      GROUP BY stateID
    ) locgrp
    ON s.stateID = locgrp.stateID
```

---

If some Locations are split into Areas that are in different States, then your design seems all right. Use this:

```
SELECT 
    STATES.name    AS state
  , LOCATIONS.name AS location
  , AREAS.name     AS area
  , locgrp.locCnt  AS locationsInState 
FROM STATES
  LEFT JOIN AREAS
    ON STATES.stateID = AREAS.stateID
  LEFT JOIN LOCATIONS
    ON AREAS.locID = LOCATIONS.locID
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT stateID
           , COUNT(DISTINCT locID) AS locCnt
      FROM AREAS
      GROUP BY stateID
    ) AS locgrp
    ON STATES.stateID = locgrp.stateID
```

or (similar to what you tried):

```
SELECT 
    STATES.name    AS state
  , LOCATIONS.name AS location
  , A.name         AS area
  , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT locID)
      FROM AREAS a2
      WHERE a2.stateID = A.stateID
    )              AS locationsInState 
FROM STATES
  LEFT JOIN AREAS A
    ON STATES.stateID = A.stateID
  LEFT JOIN LOCATIONS
    ON A.locID = LOCATIONS.locID
```

Comment: You would have problems adding "Mississipi River" location split into areas in different states.

Comment: @piotm: I assumed a 1-to-many relationship between States and Locations. If the relationship is many-to-many, then another middle table (StateLocation) will be needed as well.

Comment: @piotm, @WuLongTi: If a Location can be split into areas in different states, then your design seems all right. The middle table is in fact your "AREAS" table. I'll add a different answer/query.

Comment: @ypercube: sigh.. so close.  I got `#1054 - Unknown column 'STATE.stateID' in 'on clause'` when I ran you're second query; and `#1054 - Unknown column 'a.stateID' in 'where clause'` when running the third. Same frustrating errors I've been seeing too.  sigh...  You are correct in your assumption though, there are some locations that service areas across state lines.. other wise I could make use of the address field that the actual LOCATIONS table has...

Comment: @WuLongTi: Typos. Fixed, try again.

Comment: @ypercube: that did it; my colleague gave me a piece that fit in place too that ended up being nearly exactly the same as your third query.  Awesome job sir, thank you for your help ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.state as state, l.name as locname, count( l.locID ) as num, a.name as areaname
FROM areas a
JOIN locations l ON a.locID = l.locID
JOIN states s ON s.stateID = a.stateID
GROUP BY l.locID, s.stateID
```

will give output:

```
state       locname   locs  areaname
Florida     Orlando   2     Area1
Florida     Brevard   1     Area3
New Jersey  North NJ  2     Area4
New Jersey  South NJ  1     Area6
California  B Hills   1     Area7
California  East LA   1     Area8
California  SanFran   1     Area9
```

However if you need every area listed use query:

```
SELECT s.state AS state, 
       l.name AS locname, 
       ( SELECT count( a1.name ) FROM areas a1
         WHERE a1.locID = a.locID
         AND a1.stateID = a.stateID ) AS locs,
       a.name
FROM areas a
JOIN locations l ON a.locID = l.locID
JOIN states s ON s.stateID = a.stateID
```

which will give you output:

```
state       locname   locs  areaname
Florida     Orlando   2     Area1
Florida     Orlando   2     Area2
Florida     Brevard   1     Area3
New Jersey  North NJ  2     Area4
New Jersey  North NJ  2     Area5
New Jersey  South NJ  1     Area6
California  B Hills   1     Area7
California  East LA   1     Area8
California  SanFran   1     Area9
```

Comment: not sure what 'locs' is pulling in your example... what I need though is the total number of locations in the state so given the sample data I should have:

|FL|Orlando|3|Area1
|FL|Orlando|3|Area2
|FL|Brevard|3|Area3
|NJ|N.NJ   |3|Area4
|NJ|N.NJ   |3|Area5
|NJ|S.NJ   |3|Area6
|CA|B.Hills|3|Area7
|CA|E.LA   |3|Area8
|CA|SanFran|3|Area9

Sorry if there was any confusion